# Type visibilty for a header Share a header file shared between native and managed clients

Tags: c++-cli, preprocessor

I have a header file that is included by both a native cpp file and a managed cpp file(compiled with /clr).  It includes only native types, but I want to specify that the native types are visible outside the assembly
(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dffacbw(VS.80).aspx).

Essentially, I want:

```
public class NativeClass  // The public makes this visible outside the assembly.
{

};
```

If I include this code from a native cpp, I get the following error:

```
error C3381: 'NativeClass' : assembly access specifiers are only available in code compiled with a /clr option
```

### Attempted solution:

I'm currently using a preprocessor solution that causes the public to appear when compiling with the managed client, but it does not appear for the native client:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus_cli
#define CLR_ASSEMBLY_ACCESS_SPECIFIER__Public public
#else
#define CLR_ASSEMBLY_ACCESS_SPECIFIER__Public 
#endif 

CLR_ASSEMBLY_ACCESS_SPECIFIER__Public
class NativeClass      
{

};
```

### Question:

Is this the appropriate way to achieve this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `make_public` pragma listed on the MSDN page you linked to?

Otherwise, the solution you have is perfectly valid.  I'm curious to know why you want to export native types from a CLR assembly though.

Comment: I can use the make_public, but that seems to be more for fixing the issue when you can't modify the header file in question.  Since I own the header file, I wanted to "properly" make it public.

Comment: I want to make the Native type visible so I can have a method like `ManagedClass ^ GetManagedFromNative(const NativeClass & native)` be visible to another assembly.  If I don't make the NativeClass public, then the call to call the method `GetManagedFromNative` causes `Error C3767 'function' candidate function(s) not accessible`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19dh8yat(VS.80).aspx.