# C++/CLI "could not import member" warning when using shared_ptr as argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, shared-ptr

I have the following interface in C++/CLI:

```
public interface class ISharedPtrInterface
{
    void PrintSharedPtr(std::shared_ptr<std::wstring> ptr);
};
```

Which is implemented as follows:

```
public ref class SharedPtrClass : public ISharedPtrInterface
{
public:
    virtual void PrintSharedPtr(std::shared_ptr<std::wstring> ptr)
    {
        System::Console::WriteLine(gcnew System::String(ptr->c_str()));
    };
};
```

Compiling in Visual Studio 2010, I get the following warning:

```
1>TestSharedPtrInterface.cpp(8): warning C4679: 'ISharedPtrInterface::PrintSharedPtr' : could not import member  
1>          This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'ISharedPtrInterface ' from assembly 'AnotherCLRProject, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

If I run the compiled method, I get the following runtime error:

`Method 'PrintSharedPtr' in type 'SharedPtrClass' from assembly 'CLRProject, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.`

The error does not occur if using a straight std::wstring in the interface/implementation.  Can anyone explain why?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but I know you don't need the wstring in a unique_ptr

Comment: This is just a simple example, to reproduce an error that I am getting in a much larger project.  I know I don't need the shared_ptr in this case, but I would like to understand the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing native and managed types at the public interface level.  That is, in this case you have a public managed interface method which takes native types as parameter.  In general, this isn't a great idea, since you can't easily use these methods from a managed language like C# since you can't supply the native type.

The problem here has to do with the visibility of native types:  by default all native types are private.  When it tries to import `ISharedPtrInterface::PrintSharedPtr` it needs to have have access to the interface (which it does since it is public) and access to all parameter types.

You can mark native types as public using `make_public` or directly marking them public (when compiling with /clr).

The problem is that there is *no way* to make templated types public (make_public does not work on them).

See:

- [Best workaround for compiler error C2158: make_public does not support native template types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4121249/495262)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9213016/495262

Comment: Thanks - I got round it in the end by a combination of wrapping native types and the make_public pragma, but your explanation helped me understand why I needed to do that!